# How to find a pattern in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pattern-matching

I want to find the following pattern in a column in a pandas dataframe:

> two occurrences of 1 before a 0   then a 0 and two occurrences of 1
> after 0

there can be a gap or gaps (0) between the ones before and after 0

for example :

```
    11 0 11
 0r 101 0 11
 0r 1001 0 1001
```

all of the are acceptable,
I would like to assign a group number to all the rows that belong to a pattern an id

let's say i have the following pandas Dataframe for each group of  P and L i want to find the pattern and assign a sequence id to it:

```
 P   L   date     S
 1   1   1        1
 1   1   2        1
 1   1   3        0
 1   1   4        1
 1   1   5        1
 2   1   1        1
 2   1   2        0
 2   1   3        1
 2   1   4        0
 2   1   5        1
 2   1   6        1
 2   1   7        1
 2   1   8        1
 2   1   9        0
 2   1   10       1
 2   1   11       0
 2   1   12       1
```

the desired resulted dataframe would be:

```
 P   L   date     S     id
 1   1   1        1     1
 1   1   2        1     1
 1   1   3        0     1
 1   1   4        1     1
 1   1   5        1     1
 2   1   1        1     1
 2   1   3        1     1
 2   1   4        0     1
 2   1   5        1     1
 2   1   6        1     1
 2   1   7        1     2 
 2   1   8        1     2
 2   1   9        0     2
 2   1   10       1     2
 2   1   12       1     2
```

id column is assigned based on the occurrence of the pattern in each P L group and as you can see rows that does not belong to the pattern are dropped.

here is the sql solution in snowflake:

```
 select
     p,
     l,
     date,
     s,
     ids
 from tbl
     match_recognize(
         partition by p, l
         order by date
         measures
             match_number() as ids
         all rows per match
         after match skip to next row
         pattern((no_campaign {- campaign* -}){ 2} no_campaign campaign+ 
 no_campaign ({- campaign* -} no_campaign){ 2 })
         define
             campaign as s = 0,
             no_campaign as s = 1
     )
 order by p, l, ids, date
```

Comment: Lets say the pattern in your rows within a group is like `11 0 11 0 11 0 11`.  Here the 2nd and 3rd '11' pair will be part of 2 squences, so how do you assign `id` to those rows?

Comment: to answer your question one combination of P, L, date can have more than one id, so they can be stacked, that's actually a very good example that you mentioned.

Comment: The example in your question can be done by iterating once on `S` values, but my example above now makes it complex. Can you edit your question to include this example and then show your expected output? I didn't get your "stacked" `id` result.

Comment: why was  `2   1   2        0` dropped but not  `2   1   1        1` ?

Comment: I have put the sql version of solution which works well in snowflakes, hopefully it helps to understand the problem

Comment: this qustion is probably better representation of the original problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67883524/look-for-patterns-in-a-column-of-pandas-dataframe-based-on-the-value-of-other-co