# calculate a value in a row based on before and after rows in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
 p l w s_w  v
 1 1 1  1   2
 1 1 2  1   2
 1 1 3  0   5
 1 1 4  1   5
 1 1 5  1   5
 2 1 1  1   1
 2 1 2  0   2
 2 1 3  0   3
 2 1 4  0   4
 2 1 5  1   5
 2 1 6  1   4
```

i want to have a new column
where in each row  if the value of s_w is 1,
its value is sum(v) in two previous rows ( not necessarily successive ) where s_w==1
and  sum(v) for two following rows ( not necessarily successive),  again where s_w==1 so sum(v) + sum(v).

I am not interested in any number of zeros between

so resulted dataframe looks like this:

```
 p l w s_w  v  c_s
 1 1 1  1   2   Null
 1 1 2  1   2   Null
 1 1 3  0   5   Null
 1 1 4  1   5   10
 1 1 5  1   5   13
 2 1 1  1   1   19
 2 1 2  0   2  Null
 2 1 3  0   3  Null
 2 1 4  0   4  Null
 2 1 5  1   5  Null
 2 1 6  1   4  Null
```

last two rows value will Null because there are no two 1s after them ( n the other words sum before and after only if there are two 1s in previous and following rows( not necessarily successive, otherwise Null)

A new Edit to the original question:

for each group of P,l if only the value in check column is 1 then find the above mentioned pattern in s_w columns and sum(v) of two previous rows where s_w==1 ( not necessarily successive) and also  sum(v) of two following rows where s_w==1 ( not necessarily successive)

```
 p l w s_w check v
 1 1 1  1     0   2
 1 1 2  1     0   2
 1 1 3  0     0   5
 1 1 4  1     0   5
 1 1 5  1     1   5
 2 1 1  1     0   1
 2 1 2  0     0   2
 2 1 3  0     0   3
 2 1 4  0     0   4
 2 1 5  1     0   5
 2 1 6  1     0   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is filtered rows with `1` and use `rolling sum` with shift values for correct align:

```
s = df.loc[df['s_w'].eq(1), 'v']

df['c_s'] = s.rolling(2).sum().shift().add(s.iloc[::-1].rolling(2).sum().shift())
print (df)
    p  l  w  s_w  v   c_s
0   1  1  1    1  2   NaN
1   1  1  2    1  2   NaN
2   1  1  3    0  5   NaN
3   1  1  4    1  5  10.0
4   1  1  5    1  5  13.0
5   2  1  1    1  1  19.0
6   2  1  2    0  2   NaN
7   2  1  3    0  3   NaN
8   2  1  4    0  4   NaN
9   2  1  5    1  5   NaN
10  2  1  6    1  4   NaN
```

Another idea:

```
df['c_s'] = s.shift(-1).add(s.shift(-2)).add(s.shift(2)).add(s.shift(1))
```

EDIT:

Solution per groups:

```
s = df[df['s_w'].eq(1)]

f = lambda x: x.rolling(2).sum().shift()
df['c_s'] = s.groupby(['p','l'])['v'].apply(f).add(s.iloc[::-1].groupby(['p','l'])['v'].apply(f))
```

---

```
g = df[df['s_w'].eq(1)].groupby(['p','l'])['v']
df['c_s'] = g.shift(-1).add(g.shift(-2)).add(g.shift(2)).add(g.shift(1))
```

Comment: sorry, i made a mistake in the resulted dataframe, i want to sum(v) for both before and after but in the resulted dataframe i just calculated the sum of two previous rows i'll edit it, could you please edit the answer accordingly?

Comment: Great!, thanks, how can i change it in a way to be applied separately for each P,l group ? so look for rows before and after only inside the P,l group( combination)

Comment: @chessosapiens - Added some ideas, can you test?

Comment: the group solution works fine on the example df, should return nan for all the rows.

Comment: how can we change the answer in a way that both before rows and after rows be multiplied by a weight array for example weight =np.array([0.1,0.5])  and then add them together?

Comment: @chessosapiens - Sure, for first use `f = lambda x: x.rolling(2).agg(lambda x: (x * weight).sum()).shift()` and fior second `df['c_s'] = g.shift(-1).mul(weight[1]).add(g.shift(-2).mul(weight[0])).add(g.shift(2).mul(weight[0])).add(g.shift(1).mul(weight[1]))`

Comment: Tha't great! thanks, actually this question is related to a question that i asked previously and it is unanswered yet, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67800931/how-to-find-a-pattern-in-a-pandas-dataframe, i'd really appreciate if you can help with that. the purpose is that to find the pattern inside each group and when ever it is detected, all the rows will be given an ID, each row can be associated with several occurrences of the pattern so may be associated with several Ids

Comment: @chessosapiens - I see, really complicated.

Comment: well, i have the sql version of the solution that works well in snowflake: i put it in the question

Comment: select
    p,
    l,
    date,
    s,
    ids
from tbl
    match_recognize(
        partition by p, l
        order by date
        measures
            match_number() as ids
        all rows per match
        after match skip to next row
        pattern((no_campaign {- campaign* -}){ 2} no_campaign campaign+ no_campaign ({- campaign* -} no_campaign){ 2 })
        define
            campaign as s = 0,
            no_campaign as s = 1
    )
order by p, l, ids, date

Comment: sql solution uses the snow flake pattern matching

Comment: @chessosapiens - ya, never usinf snow flake matching, so hard for me, sorry :(

Comment: i have difficulty to generalize the solution to my original problem, i have made an Edit to the question which resembles the original question, i'd really appreciate if you could help.

Comment: or should i create a new question?

Comment: @chessosapiens - I try understand it, but failed. So maybe new question should be fine with more explanation.

Comment: Sure, here is the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67883524/look-for-patterns-in-a-column-of-pandas-dataframe-based-on-the-value-of-other-co  hopefully it is clear enough

Comment: I also added some nice visualization here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67883524/look-for-patterns-in-a-column-of-pandas-dataframe-based-on-the-value-of-other-co